# Import/export ios data (e.g. CoreData) from/to local files on Mac

Tags: ios, import, export, core-data-migration

I'm developing an app with a feature that needs to import and export from local files.
I think a solution should be similar to what GoodReader does that allows users to import files to iPhone or to export files to local disks. Would be nice if you provide some links or clues to this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You may use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to create and read the files.